# How can I get the day / hour traffic view in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

On Google Analytics mobile, I can get the following view, which I find really useful. How can I get it for Google Analytics on desktop?

[image: View]

Comment: Questions on Google Analytics are much better suited for [webmasters.se], not here. This should have been migrated there.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like this exact chart type is available on the desktop version.

For equivalent data, you might try drilling into Behavior > Overview > Hourly.

Find more here (plus a custom report configuration) at this Stack Overflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24781297/896802